# Replace search current page contents with search contents

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have few components i.e. `about`, `home`, `contact`, `header`, `footer`, `search`.
I am using `react-router-dom` for routing between all the pages. In `App.js` I am loading all the components based on routes however, for `footer` and `header` I do not need route, they are loaded in all pages. `Header` consists of navigation and a `search` component. `search` component is where the user enter text to search for things. Now this `header` with `search` component is rendered in all pages because I am using it in `App.js` file. Now what I want is when user is searching something, **I want the contents of current page to be replaced with search contents. How can I do this?**

Here is my App.js

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import About from "./about";
import Contact from "./contact";
import Home from "./home";
import Header from "./header";
import Footer from "./footer";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Header />
      <div>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact={true}>
            <Home />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/home" exact={true}>
            <Home />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/about">
            <About />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/contact">
            <Contact />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
      <Footer />
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

here is my header

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Search from "./search";
const Header = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to="home">Home</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="about">About</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="contact">Contact</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <Search />
    </>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

here is my search component

```
import { useState } from "react";
const Search = () => {
  const apiKey = "test key";
  const baseUrl = "https://content.guardianapis.com/";
  const [items, setItems] = useState();

  const searchNews = async (event) => {
    const query = event.target.value;
    if (query === "") {
      const news = await fetchNews("news", 15, 1);
      console.log();
      setItems(news.response.results);
      return;
    }
    console.log(query);
    const news = await fetchNews(query, 15, 1);
    setItems(news.response.results);
  };

  const fetchNews = async (section, pageSize, page) => {
    const url = `${baseUrl}${section}?page-size=${pageSize}&page=${page}&api-key=${apiKey}`;
    const news = await fetch(url);
    return await news.json();
  };
  return (
    <>
      <input
        type="text"
        name="search"
        placeholder="Enter search term"
        onChange={searchNews}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default Search;
```

Here is the link to codesandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/muddy-forest-4vbgs?file=/src/search.js:0-970

You can find the rest of the components on that link above. Please help me how can I achieve this scenario?

Comment: I'm sure even you can achieve it with an emit from search component to parent component, it's a bad practice. For a better UX, I'd suggest you add a search button, listen on click event of the button and send user to a new search component page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would abstract the search fetching logic from the `Search` component into a React context that various other components of your app can consume.

SearchContext.js

```
import { createContext, useEffect, useContext, useState } from "react";

export const SearchContext = createContext({
  search: "",
  searchResult: [],
  setSearch: () => {}
});

export const useSearch = () => useContext(SearchContext);

const SearchProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const apiKey = "test key";
  const baseUrl = "https://content.guardianapis.com/";

  const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const searchNews = async () => {
      if (search.length < 3) {
        const news = await fetchNews("news", 15, 1);
        console.log();
        setItems(news.response.results);
        return;
      }
      console.log(search);
      const news = await fetchNews(search, 15, 1);
      setItems(news.response.results);
    };

    const fetchNews = async (section, pageSize, page) => {
      const url = `${baseUrl}${section}?page-size=${pageSize}&page=${page}&api-key=${apiKey}`;
      const news = await fetch(url);
      return await news.json();
    };

    searchNews();
  }, [search]);

  return (
    <SearchContext.Provider
      value={{
        search,
        searchResult: items,
        setSearch: (e) => setSearch(e.target.value)
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </SearchContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default SearchProvider;
```

Provide the context in index.js

```
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import SearchProvider from "./SearchContext";

import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <SearchProvider>
      <App />
    </SearchProvider>
  </StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

search.js - set the search value

```
import { useSearch } from "./SearchContext";

const Search = () => {
  const { setSearch } = useSearch();

  return (
    <>
      <input
        type="text"
        name="search"
        placeholder="Enter search term"
        onChange={setSearch}
      />
    </>
  );
};
```

In any of the route components display the search value and/or results.

home.js

```
import { useSearch } from './SearchContext';

const Home = () => {
  const { search } = useSearch();
  return (
    <>
      <h3>Home page</h3>
      <div>Search value: {search}</div>
    </>
  );
};
```

#### Demo

[image: Edit replace-search-current-page-contents-with-search-contents]

#### Update

If you want to add a loading indicator then it's likely the same as you've done previously.

1. Add an `isLoading` state to the context.
2. Set `isLoading` true when fetching and
3. Set `isLoading` false when fetching complete.
4. Consume the `isLoading` state from the context.

SearchProvider:

```
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  const searchNews = async () => {
    console.log(search);

    setIsLoading(true); // <-- start loading

    const news = await fetchNews(search.length ? search : "news", 15, 1);

    setItems(news);
    setIsLoading(false); // <-- clear loading
  };

  const fetchNews = async (section, pageSize, page) => {
    const url = `${baseUrl}${section}?page-size=${pageSize}&page=${page}&api-key=${apiKey}`;
    const news = await fetch(url);
    return await news.json();
  };

  searchNews();
}, [search]);
```

UI example:

```
const Home = () => {
  const { isLoading, search, searchResult } = useSearch();

  return (
    <>
      <h3>Home page</h3>
      {isLoading ? (
        <h1>LOADING...</h1>
      ) : (
        <div>
          <div>Search value: {search}</div>
          {searchResult..map( ..... )}
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Great stuff. One question how can I add a loader indicator to search context so when the search is happening I want to show a loader and when it is completed the remove a loader? I normal component, I usually add a loading state which is boolean and set it to true or false show and hide loader. how can I achieve this in contexts?

Comment: @Om3ga It's the same as you've likely done previously. I updated my answer and linked codesandbox.

Comment: That works perfectly. Thanks a lot for that. I just stumbled upon another case. Now I have multiple contexts there are 2 to be exact but can have more than that. They way I am adding both contexts to the application is by `<React.StrictMode>
    <ContextOneProvider>
      <ContextTwoProvider>
        <App />
      </ContextTwoProvider>
    </ContextOneProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,` in my index.js file. Is this something correct? If not could you give me a better solution to add multiple contexts?

Comment: @Om3ga React context providers all follow a fairly simple pattern, and you can have as many as you need; I see no issue with the code in your comment.